# Does pushing a character onto a stack change the string it comes from?

Tags: java, stack, substring, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have a hw assignment that asks to convert infix expressions to postfix expressions.

Edit: 
What is suppose to happen: 
   Input: (5)  Output: 5; Input: (1+1) Output: 11+; Input = ((9/3)-2)
Output = 93/2- 
What happens with this code: Input: (5)  (Code keeps running)

I've debugged it and the problem seems to my second while loop. It just keeps looping and I'm unsure as to why. I thought pushing the substring onto the stack update the loop and change the string from (5) to 5)

```
// data fields 
   StackInterface<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
   String output = "";
   int first = 0;
   int second = 1;
   String oneChar = infixExpression.substring(first,second);

  //while   
  while (infixExpression.length()>0){
     while(oneChar.equals("(")){
         stack.push(oneChar);
         first ++; 
         second ++;
       }
       //if char is ), pop off stack while char is not (
       //add to string operators, add to output
        while(oneChar.equals(")")){
         while (oneChar != "(" && stack.empty() == false){
         String popOperator = stack.pop();
          output = output + popOperator;

         //moves to next char of String  
           first ++; 
           second ++;

         }//end of while loop

         }
         while((oneChar == "*") || (oneChar == "/") || (oneChar == "%") || (oneChar == "+") ||(oneChar == "-")){

          stack.push(oneChar);

         //moves to next char of String  
           first ++; 
           second ++;
          } 
         //error checking input is int
         try{

            Integer.parseInt(oneChar);
             output = output + oneChar;

          //moves to next char of String  
             first ++; 
             second ++;
         } catch (InputMismatchException e){
          System.out.print("Not a valid expression"); 
          }
         }//end of while loop
     System.out.print("Postfix Expression: " + output);
```

}

Comment: You say you do not think you are doing it right. I would be helpful if you gave us a couple of examples of expressions you are feeding in to this code to test it, what what your code is vs. what you are expecting it to do. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

> Does pushing a character onto a stack change the string it comes from?

No.  Repeat after me ... "Strings are immutable.  They CANNOT change."

---

Looking at your code, there seem to be some major problems at the algorithmic level.  Hint: You should not need a four-deep nested loop to handle the brackets.  In the top level loop you should the logic should be something like:

```
if operand then do something, 
else if operator then do something, 
else if '(' then do something, 
else if ')' then do something, 
else error.
```

Comment: I think you need to take a big step back, and try to understand the algorithm you are trying to implement.  Start with a pencil and paper and work it "by hand".  Once you understand the algorithm clearly, then you can try to write it in Java.  But clearly, you cannot update the value of a string, because strings cannot be changed.